# Keep image aligned in form when resizing

Tags: html, css, webflow

I have this image (the curve):

[image]

It shows part of the next section because the image form is narrower on the part and the width is over 1000px aprox.

My CSS for it is:

```
.img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

It should **always** look like this:

[image]

How could I make that happen independently of viewport width?

Answer (score 3):

The css property "background-position" can be very helpful with centering/placing an image in a certain position so it sizes better across responsive screens.

Have you tried displaying the image as a background image of a custom div which would have the properties you listed above, in a way similar to something like this:

```
.image-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('my-image.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
}
```

Or something to that equivalent? I can't say exactly how to set background-position with your image as I'm unsure of its dimensions and where that curve lies in the image.

There some good info about the [background-position property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/) here.

Comment: The thing is that when resizing, because the "shape" of that image it makes it look wrong... Like I need it to be glued with the previous section.

Comment: Have you tried setting hard heights and widths then if it has to be an exact match, and then adding media queries for when that needs to be adjusted based on screen size? It sounds like it might require something a bit more tailored like that.